# adding custom map to maps package

Tags: r, maps

I want to be able to use map.where function on a map that is not currently available in the `MapEnv` in the `maps` package--such as these maps of Brazil: http://www.usp.br/nereus/?dados=brasil. They go into a more granular level than what is available in the `maps` package.

Is there anyway to add them to the package data so that they can be used by `maps.where`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is usually possible to load shp files into map(). You will need extra packages to read the shp files first, though. Also, you will have to know the name of the field that names the polygons.
For instance, using one of the maps from your link:

```
> ufebrasil <- rgdal::readOGR("UFEBRASIL.shp")
> names(ufebrasil)
[1] "ID"         "CD_GEOCODU" "NM_ESTADO"  "NM_REGIAO" 
> mymap=maps::SpatialPolygons2map(ufebrasil, namefield="NM_ESTADO")
> map.where(mymap, -48.6, -26.46)
[1] "SANTA CATARINA:1"
```

You can also simply call

> mymap=maps::map(ufebrasil, namefield="NM_ESTADO")

to plot a map and give the same map data as above (map() will call SpatialPolygons2map automatically if necessary).